# Acceder al valor de una variable que esta en una funcion A a una funcion B

Tags: javascript, json, array

Hola nuevamente alguien me puede ayudar con este problema. Estoy tratando de acceder al valor de una función que esta en A para ponerla en una función B con el valor que tiene en A. De antemano gracias:

En este codigo obtengo el id de una fila seleccionada en mi grid(jqxGrid)

```
   $('#grid').on('rowclick', function(event) {
                dataRecord = $('#gid').jqxGrid('getrowdata', event.args.rowindex);
             var resultado = dataRecord.id_Persona; // El valor de resultado es el que guarda los id por cada fila seleccionada de mi grid

                });
```

Aquí quiero acceder a la variable con el resultado que guarda dentro de la otra función.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "frmBI.aspx/ListarPersonas",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: '{id_Persona:"' + resultado + '"}', //aqui trato de acceder a la variable con el valor que tiene en la otra funcion.
```

Answer (score 0):

La variable `resultado` es local al handler `rowclick`.  Puedes declarar la variable fuera del handler y asi puedes usarla en la llamada ajax.  Algo asi:

```
var resultado = null;
$('#grid').on('rowclick', function(event) {
                dataRecord = $('#gid').jqxGrid('getrowdata', event.args.rowindex);
                resultado = dataRecord.id_Persona; 

 });

 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "frmBI.aspx/ListarPersonas",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: '{id_Persona:"' + resultado + '"}',
```

Comment: Hola @alanfcm ya le intente asi pero me marca el siguiente mensaje

{"Message":"null no es un valor válido para Int32.","StackTrace":"   en System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)\r\n

Comment: @SHINOBI Puedes declarar la variable así `var resultado = "";` yo utilizo este método y me funciona bien, puedes intentarlo, comenta el resultado. :)

Comment: Tambien puedes inicializar a 0 asi: `var resultado = 0;`

Comment: hola @VickMuñoz ya lo probe y me muestra este mensaje: {"Message":" no es un valor válido para Int32.","StackTrace":"   en System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type,

Comment: hola @alanfcm gracias por tu ayuda pero al ponerle 0 no me muestra nada.

Comment: Me parece que la llamada ajax tiene que ir dentro del handler.

Answer (score 0):

a ver de donde sale `id_Persona`? es una variable global? Tengo en mente algo asi, pero no se  de donde sale `id_Persona`

```
 var resultado= $('#grid').on('rowclick', function(event) {
                dataRecord = $('#gid').jqxGrid('getrowdata', event.args.rowindex);
                dataRecord.id_Persona; 

                });
```

incluso puedes intentar:

```
$('#grid').on('rowclick', function(event) {
                    var dataRecord = $('#gid').jqxGrid('getrowdata', event.args.rowindex);
                    });
var resultado = dataRecord.id_Persona;
```

Prueba a ver.

Comment: Claro estoy dando por sentado que tu función se ejecuta correctamente

Comment: Hola @henryscode mis funciones se ejecutan de manera correcta. Lo que quiero hacer es declarar la funcion de manera global para acceder a ella desde otra función pero con el resultado que trae de la primera funcion que es  resultado = dataRecord.id_Persona;

¿De donde sale id_Persona? Este sale al darle click a mi grid anidado padre. cada vez que le doy clic este me muestra su id por lo que aqui quiero pararlo como parametro: data: '{id_Persona:"' + resultado + '"}', Gracias.

Comment: prueba colocando un alert (resultado) al final de la primera función, para verificar que la primera función guarda los datos en la variable resultado correctamente, de ser asi entonces el problema esta en como accedes a la variable en el ajax

Comment: Hola @henryscode ya le coloque un alert y si me saca los resultados de los id al hacerle clic.

Comment: ok entonces si hasta ese punto hace lo que quieres entonces la funcion A esta correcta, ahora verificamos el ajax. Segun entiendo la variable resultado  ya viene con id_Persona. Entonces el el ajax no es necesario que coloques id_Persona nuevamente. 
prueba:
data: resultado,

Comment: hola @henryscode he puesto un alert en mi segunda funcion y no me devuelve los valores que tiene en la primera estos se pierden. Tengo declarada mi variable de forma global como var resultado = null; Por otro lado lo ejecute como menciones y me sale este mensaje:  {"Message":"Se ha pasado un objeto no válido. Se esperaba \u0027:\u0027 o \u0027}\u0027. (5): {res}","StackTrace":"   en System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeDictionary(Int32 depth)\r\n

Comment: el problema esta en data: ... pasalo asi a ver si es lo que pienso: data: consulta:resultado
sino
data: {consulta:resultado},

Ahora el documento que recibe el objeto, lo recibira como "consulta", pero puedes cambiar eso luego y pones lo que prefieras

Comment: Hola @Henryscode el problema aun persiste.